# Retrieve row data according to the column value

Tags: php, sql, substring

I am trying to get the renewal_date column and get the month to check is that the exact month I want, and if so display the details of that record. My query is:

```
select domain_name, renewal_date
from hosting_details
where substr(renewal_date,-5,-3) = '09'
```

This doesn't give any result, but when I run below query I can retrieve results:

```
select domain_name, renewal_date
from hosting_details
where renewal_date = '2015-09-03'
```

I don't want to hard code the date, I want to retrieve any details which is in 09th month. How can I do it?

Comment: Which dbms is used? (You've got several answers with product specific SQL...)

Answer (score 1):

You should not perform a function on your (primary) WHERE statement. It will not use the index and perform a full table scan.

```
SELECT domain_name,renewal_date FROM hosting_details
  WHERE renewal_date >= '01-09-2015' AND renewal_date < '01-10-2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below :

```
select domain_name,renewal_date from hosting_details where
date_format(renewal_date, '%m' ) = '09'
```